# to return JSON using JAX-RS

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jetty, jax-rs

I am trying to return JSON of SOLRDocList type which is :

```
{numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]}{"start":0,"empty":true,"class":"class org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList","numFound":0}
```

However since I am using Service class as :

```
@POST
@Path("/userQuery")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SolrDocumentList userQuery(String p){  
  int sizy;
  String stry;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  SolrDocument doc = null;
  SolrDocumentList docList = null;

  List<String> arr = new ArrayList();
  StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(p,",");
  while(token.hasMoreElements()){
      stry = token.nextToken();
      arr.add(stry);
  }

  Set<String> xrr = new HashSet<String>(arr);

      SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(createQuery(arr));
      query.setIncludeScore(false);
      query.setFields("country_code,last_name,raw_location");
      query.setParam("wt", "json");
      System.out.println(query);
      QueryResponse qr = authorSearcher.query(query);
      docList = qr.getResults();

  return docList;
}
```

> ```
> Error is :
> ```

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList, and Java type class org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList, and MIME media type application/json was not found
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
```

I want to know if there is any possible way to convert the SOLRDocList type which is JSON into the supported type to resolve this issue?
 Thanks for your time !

Comment: Sadly I don't know much about Solr and its structures. However, you might consider trying the message body writers that come with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider). Or you can make your own JAXB wrapper objects for SolrDocumentList, and return that instead of the SolrDocumentList itself....

Comment: {numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]}{"start":0,"empty":true,"class":"class org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList","numFound":0} this is a json object , can be returned in form of string but problem is at other end its a string not a JSON object , can we add: "" to its field and make it as json object

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, since I am using solr4j , this library doesn't support JSON as a output , in such situation using external library or :

```
Map<Integer,Object> solrDocMap = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();
              int counter = 1;
              for(Map singleDoc: docList)
              {
                  solrDocMap.put(counter, new JSONObject(singleDoc));
                  counter++;
              }
              try {
                  returnResults.put("docs",solrDocMap);
                    }
```

and when you want to return a JSON string instead  going with 3rd party libraries , go with something like:

```
  String x = ""+returnResults;
  return x;
```